# How do I loop an animation in a Godot animation player?

Tags: godot

I'm trying to loop an idle animation that I have in an AnimationPlayer, but it keeps on only playing once. Is there any way for me to make it loop?

Answer (score 7):

You can enable the `Animation Looping` icon:

[image: A screenshot of the top right corner of the animation player, showcasing a looping blue arrow.]

The looping arrows [image: screenshot of the looping arrows in a toggled color] is the icon that allows for toggling the looping.

Comment: it will not stop in the GUI , i solved with the suggestion from above

Answer (score 7):

For Godot 4, to set the animation loop mode use `Animation.loop_mode`

https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_animation.html#enum-animation-loopmode

```
var anim : Animation= $AnimationPlayer.get_animation(anim_name)
anim.loop_mode =(Animation.LOOP_LINEAR)
```

Comment: the only way enable / disable so it wont show in the editor when looping enabled in GUI