# Problems looping in animation in godot 4

Tags: godot, godot4

I'm trying to apply a looping animation to an item in my game, I want the item to be "floating", up and down,

In the code of the uploaded image it performs this animation but only once, how to apply a looping animation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I loop an animation in a Godot animation player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75796006/how-do-i-loop-an-animation-in-a-godot-animation-player)